# write shell script similar history in console

Tags: shell, history

I try to write a simple script and store all my favor commands such as grep, find, sed.

when I use history command in shell, I can show all the historical commands with (history) I can reuse the the symbol '!'(Exclamation) to get my old commands:

Let's assume 2099 -> ls -lah  (in my history)

```
>!2099 <- ENTER

>ls -la[CURSOR]
```

when I type `'!2099 <- ENTER'`, `'ls -la[CURSOR]'` in the next line.

does anyone know how to implement it on shell script?

I have tried to remove the `'\r'` from the input string, but it does't work so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fc` command allows you to edit and list commands from your history. This is useful when scripting anything related to history. List entries with:

```
fc -ln [first] [last]
```

`-l` is the list flag, `-n` prevents display of the history numbers, `[first]` and `[last]` are the numbers from the history command. To list a single command repeat its number. So using your example:

```
cmd=$(fc -ln 2099 2099)
echo "$cmd"
```

will display `ls -la`. The output has a tab at the beginning so you can strip that off by piping `fc` through `sed 's/^\t//'` or `tr -d '\t'`